# Prevent Drupal form from being called again on submit?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms

In `Drupal 7`, I have this code.

It defines the hard-coded string `my_module_custom_route_form` as the form ID and use `drupal_get_form` to initialize a form. And there is one submit button.

Visit this route `/custom_route`, the output is

```
initialize form
```

If you submit the form, the output is

```
initialize form
submitted
```

The problem is this: **The submission of this form will call `my_module_custom_route_form` again.**

How can I prevent it from being called again on submission? If you know why Drupal does this, I would also like to know.

```
function my_module_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['custom_route'] = array(
        "page arguments" => array("my_module_custom_route_form"),
        "page callback" => "drupal_get_form",
        "access callback" => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
}

function my_module_custom_route_form($form, &$form_state){
    print_r("initialize form");
    $form = array();
    $form["button"] = array(
        "#type" => "submit",
        "#value" => "submit"
    );
    return $form;
}

function my_module_custom_route_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    print_r("<br />submitted");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

> Set $form_state['redirect'] = false in the submit handler.

See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26347/prevent-redirect-after-form-submit

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, tried, not working. The output "initialize form" appears before the "submitted". So it is not printed after the redirect but actually before running through the "submit" function. This is what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but the question is still relevant - I ran into the same problem. In my case it is definitely a problem, since the form in the block claims a queue item for processing, but when the form builder is called a second time, of course the item is blocked in the queue.

Clicking the button on a non-ajaxified form causes the page to reload. In the case of the block, this calls the block_view function, which rebuilds the form from 0.

I solved this by ajaxifying the submit button. Then the submission is called without re-viewing the block (and rebuilding the form, as is the case here). There is a nice ajax_example in the examples module, for those who are new to ajax forms.